# Index all tables from the database using Apache Solr

Tags: apache, solrj

How to index most of the tables(ex:20 table) using Apache solr

We need to add entity tag for each and every table in the dataconfig.xml?

Thanks in advance

Dilip

Answer (score 0):

I had index tables from database using solrj.

I had entered Field tag in schema.xml with user-defined name.

Sample Field Tag:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

Also refer to [Schema XML File](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/example/solr/conf/schema.xml?view=markup)

Hope it answers your doubts..